# Valor temporal a puntero

Tags: c

Buscando una forma de pasar un valor temporal a un argumento puntero de una función me tope con esto, mi pregunta es puede causar undefined behavior?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mifuncion(int *pi)
{
    printf("%d\n", *pi);
}

int main(void)
{
    mifuncion(&(int){5});
    return 0;
}
```

el resultado que me da es:

- 5

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo por el que no quieras/puedas hacer esto? `int valor = 5; mifuncion(&valor);` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> puede causar undefined behavior?

Sí

¿Por qué?

`miFuncion` espera un puntero, esto es, una variable que contiene una dirección de memoria...

- ¿Qué dirección de memoria tiene un literal?
- ¿El Sistema Operativo podría tener algo que decir al respecto? Los SO modernos tienen regiones de memoria de solo lectura y cualquier acceso de escritura implica la muerte del proceso que ejecuta la operación. De la misma manera, también comprueban si un proceso tiene acceso a la memoria a la que intenta acceder... aunque sea en modo solo lectura.
- ¿Qué pasaría si dentro de `miFuncion` te diese por modificar (con o sin intención) el valor direccionado por el puntero? ¿Un literal es modificable?

Uno de los motivos por los que C ofrece tanta potencia es porque relega la *zona gris* del estándar, es decir, código que, sin llegar a ser un error tampoco es correcto del todo, a comportamientos no definidos, es decir, cuya respuesta depende en exclusiva del compilador. Dicho de otra forma... se evita un montón de chequeos y comprobaciones para arañar más rendimiento.

No creo que te interese que tu código se pueda comportar diferente en compiladores diferentes (el comportamiento podría variar incluso al actualizar el compilador a una versión más moderna). Es probable que en una práctica no pase nada, pero en un proyecto de varios miles de líneas de código del que depende que sigas trabajando o te vayas a la calle la cosa cambia.

Como te han dicho en los comentarios, es preferible dejar de lado las prácticas de dudosa legalidad.

```
// Evitar su uso
miFuncion(&(int){5});

// Mucho más seguro
int valor = 5;
mifuncion(&valor);
```